# scroll to newly created div after ajax complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, jquery-animate

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var conv = new Markdown.Converter();
function getData(category, $target) {
    window.location.hash = category;
    $.ajax({
        url: category + ".txt",
        dataType: "text",
        type: 'GET',
        error: function (x, s, d) {
            console.log(x);
        },
        success: function (d, s, x) {
            var data = conv.makeHtml(d);
            $target.html(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log($('#' + category));
            $('html').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#' + category).scroll().top
            }, 'slow');
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var
        curr = "",
        h = window.location.hash;
    if (h !== "") {
        h = h.toLowerCase()
        h = (h.charAt(0) == '#') ? h.substr(1) : h;
        curr = h;
        getData(h, $result);
    }
    $('ul > li').on('click', function (e) {
        var
            $result = $('#content'),
            type = $(this).data('id');
        if (curr !== type) {
            getData(type, $result);
            curr = type;
        }
    });
});
```

and the `category + '.txt'` files contain some markdown text with custom `<a id="category" />` segments.

The markdown content is loaded fine in the browser but the `complete` section in AJAX call is not scrolling to the newly created `div`s and content.

Opera Dragonfly reports the following in console:

```
Object [<a id="general"/> ]
```

but the scroll animation doesn't occur. If I execute the same animate function from my console, the scroll does take place.

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

**PS**: The scroll doesn't take place in any of the browsers. So, it is not a specific browser (deprecated Opera) issue.

Comment: Have you tried scrolling `$('html, body')`?  Also, I think you want to grab the `offset()`, not the scroll: `$('#' + category).offset().top` ...

Comment: I did try `html, body`. It wasn't working with `.scroll()`. The `.offset()` seems to work. Please post it as an answer @cale_b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but from my experience the following adjustments would need to be made to your current scroll-to script:

```
// Scroll both html and body
$('html, body').animate({
    // Grab the offset (position relative to document)
    scrollTop: $('#' + category).offset().top
  }, 'slow');
```